# Does Closing A RecordSet in VB 6.0 Update the Database?

Tags: vb6, ado, recordset, vb6-migration

I am converting VB 6.0 code to VB.Net. In the VB 6.0 code I see the following use of a recordset

```
varFields = Array([set of column names])
varData = Array([matching data])
recordset.Open "[a query that will return 0 results]", connection, adOpenDynamic, adLockOptimistic
recordset.AddNew varFields, varData
recordset.Close
```

As I understand it, with adOpenDynamic, this will not update the database with out a call to Update.

Could someone explain to me if this set of code is doing anything?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the code is valid.

As [documented](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms677536%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> In *immediate update mode* ... If you pass the `Fieldlist` and `Values` arguments, ADO immediately posts the new record to the database (no `Update` call is necessary); the `EditMode` property value does not change (`adEditNone`).

Comment: Thank you. I read the documentation but must have missed that bit. You've saved me from my puzzling!